# how to specify more than one param in method for spring Cacheable key

Tags: spring, caching, spring-cache

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html#cache-annotations-cacheable-key
The link above shows how to specify a key when all the parameters for a method are not required for the cache key which is the default. But how do you specify more than one param (but not all in the method arg list) as the key for the cache in the Cacheable annotation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you know, the `key` attribute of the `@Cacheable` annotation allows [SpEL](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#expressions) to be used. In all cases, the actual key used to access the underlying `Cache` must "evaluate" to a single value.  Therefore, you must employ the power of *SpEL* to combine the `@Cacheable` method arguments that form the (unique) key.

By way of example, lets say we want to find a Book by Author, Edition and Title.  I.e., we might have a `@Cacheable` method signature like so...

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "Books", key="#author.name + #edition + #title")
Book findBook(Author author, Integer edition, String title, boolean checkWarehous, boolean includeUsed) {
 ...
}
```

As you can see, the key is a combination and subset of the method arguments.

Literally any valid *SpEL* expression used to combine the `@Cacheable` method arguments for use as a key is applicable.

For complex keys where the individual components (such as Author, Edition, Title etc) of the key are each accessible, then it is best create a custom key class (e.g. BookKey) and use a custom Spring [KeyGenerator](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html) (e.g. BookKeyGenerator) to generate the `Cache` key.  Note, the method, target class and arguments of the `@Cacheable` method (e.g. `findBook(author, edition, title, ...)`) are each made available to your custom `KeyGenerator`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

0 param: key is 0

1 param: key is the param

2 or more params: key is hashCode(param0, param1, ...)